# AEM Query Builder - exclude root folder in list results

Tags: adobe, aem, builder

I'm using AEM 6.4 and trying to sort a call upon child pages and sort them by date range using this code:

path=/content/confidential-path/2020
cq:Page
orderby=@jcr:content/main_content/datestamp/dateTime
orderby.index=true
orderby.sort=desc

**Problem:**  The root folder, 2020 is included in the list component. How do I make sure only the child pages in the 2020 folder show up and not the root folder? Note that there is also a redirect child page in the 2020 folder that I'd like to keep. All of them have datestamp components on the page aside from the redirect. I don't mind if the redirect page is last in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Add `path.self=false`

If true searches the subtree including the main node given in path,  if false searches the subtree only.